# problem launchin Laravel project with Nginx on googledrive server

Tags: laravel, nginx

i have a problem launching a Laravel proect and googlecloud server.
When i was using:
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
to lauch the website, I correctly get the page at the address http://myipserver:8000/admin/login
But when i dont use that artisan serve command, i just get the laravel home page at http://myipserver:8000/ but an error when try to access http://myipserver:8000/admin/login
I have another project that run correctly on port 80.
this i want to run on port 8000.
Those are my configuration files.

---

### nginx conf file

```
    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name _;  

        root /var/www/myfolder/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options “SAMEORIGIN”;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection “1; mode=block”;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options “nosniff”;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

            if ($http_origin = ‘’) {
                add_header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ ‘*’;
            }
            if ($http_origin != ‘’) {
                add_header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ $http_origin;
            }
                add_header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’ ‘GET, POST, OPTIONS, PU>
            add_header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ ‘Origin, Content-Type, Acce>
            add_header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’ ‘true’;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    }
```

---

### env:   (serverip is the ip of my pulic server of google drive)

```
    APP_NAME=myproject
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:jL9DH53njdw51zupUuiZ1BpxmMjQ6BijYQBBkArEmfg=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://serverip:8000
```

---

### cors.php

‘paths’ => [‘api/*’],

```
‘allowed_methods’ => [‘*’],

‘allowed_origins’ => [‘*’],

‘allowed_origins_patterns’ => [],

‘allowed_headers’ => [‘*’],

‘exposed_headers’ => [],

‘max_age’ => 0,

‘supports_credentials’ => false,
```

---

### server.php

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
     *
     * @package  Laravel
     * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
     */

    $uri = urldecode(
        parse_url($_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’], PHP_URL_PATH)
    );

    // This file allows us to emulate Apache’s “mod_rewrite” functionality from the
    // built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
    // application without having installed a “real” web server software here.
    if ($uri !== ‘/’ && file_exists(__DIR__.’/public’.$uri)) {
        return false;
    }

    require_once __DIR__.’/public/index.php’;
```

---

### kernel.php

```
        namespace App\Http;

    use App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthMiddleware;
    use App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
    {
        /**
         * The application’s global HTTP middleware stack.
         *
         * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middleware = [
            // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
            CorsMiddleware::class,
        ];

        /**
         * The application’s route middleware groups.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $middlewareGroups = [
            ‘web’ => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            ],

            ‘api’ => [
                ‘throttle:api’,
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            ],
        ];

        /**
         * The application’s route middleware.
         *
         * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $routeMiddleware = [
            ‘auth’ => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            ‘auth.basic’ => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
            ‘cache.headers’ => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
            ‘can’ => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
            ‘guest’ => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
            ‘password.confirm’ => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
            ‘signed’ => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
            ‘throttle’ => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
            ‘verified’ => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
            ‘admin.auth’ => AdminAuthMiddleware::class,
        ];
    }
```

---

### corsMiddleware.php

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class CorsMiddleware
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
        {
            $handle = $next($request);
            if(method_exists($handle, ‘header’))
            {
                $handle->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ , ‘*’)
                    ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’, ‘POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE’)
                    ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’, ‘Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application’);
            }
            return $handle;
        }
    }
```

---

I tried to check possible solutions on the web and also using gpt4 to get suggestion but i can’t get over this problem . It is probably very simple I guess.

i tried looking for similar problem on the web and also tried to solve with gpt4 suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First case: You run

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Currently, you connect from your browser to php without NGINX webserver. That reason why you can connect to PHP code

```
http://myipserver:8000/admin/login
```

Second case: You don not run

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Right now, your request from your browser will access your laravel code from NGINX webserver
and then:
I try your nginx config 
you can try by command

```
sudo nginx -t
```

```
nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

That reason why NGINX can not run your code.

Solution:I think you remove

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

in

```
 location ~ \.php$ {}
```

Bonus:
When use multi-projects you can you sub-domain for url more beatiful like this:

```
abc.yourdomain.abc
abc2.yourdomain.abc
```